# How to have same entity setting for multiple symfony bundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

If the entity setting is the same for multiple bundle, do I still need to repeat it for each bundle?

```
            mappings: # Required
                     ApplicationUserBundle:
                                         is_bundle: false
                                         dir: doctrine/Entities
                                         prefix: Entities
                                         type: staticphp
                     ApplicationAdminBundle:
                                         is_bundle: false
                                         dir: doctrine/Entities
                                         prefix: Entities
                                         type: staticphp
```

Or is there a way to set the same entity setting for several bundle without repeating them?

Comment: No don't defnine it in each bundle. You can use depenties between yours differents bundle

Comment: Please explain a bit more with example.

Comment: Since you are overriding the default settings then yes, you need to specify the parameters each bundle.  I suppose you could search for where the default settings are defined in the doctrine bridge code and adjust things there but it's hardly worth the effort.  By the way, consider changing Entities to Entity.  I think you will find it reads better and is more in keeping with the Symfony 2 coding style (i.e. Controller directory instead of Controllers).